# UK Business Visa from India

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, business-travel

I have applied for the `UK business visa (6 months Multiple Entry)`. I have submitted the following details

1. Company Cover Letter
2. Invite Letter from UK based office
3. Salary Slips
4. Bank Statements
5. Tax return papers

In both `Cover Letter and the Invite letter` it is clearly mentioned that travel related cost (including Fooding, Lodging, Air Tickets, Miscellaneous Expenditures) will be borne by the company. Even in the misc section of the Visa Form, I have mentioned about this clearly. Also My company is `BEP` registered. My only worry is around the `Personal financial savings as it's not much`. Is there any chance of Visa getting rejected based on `"Insufficient Funds"`? This is the first time I have applied for (any) Visa.

Answer (score 4):

Well, both 'it depends', and 'yes'.  The British (and other governments) are notorious for not specifying how much you're required to have in your account when applying for a visa.  This tends to be because it's on a case-by-case basis.

If you clearly show that the majority of your costs will be covered by the company, then logically, they won't expect you to require as much money to support yourself as say, a backpacker going over there for 6 months, or a family with just the one person working to support all of them.

The point of the funds check is to ensure you have more than enough funds to cover yourself during your time there.  Unfortunately, only the person evaluating your application can determine that for us.

So long story short, not the answer you were probably hoping for - yes it can still happen - but the good news is that you've done the right thing - tried to clearly demonstrate that many of your expenses will be covered by the company.  For now, you can only wait.  Good luck!